# Extracting specific string format of digits

Tags: python, text, python-re

Let us suppose we  have text like this :

`text ="new notebook was sold  8 times before  13:30 in given shop"`

here we have  3 number presented, one is single digit `8` and  last two are two digit numbers, `13`,`30`, main point is , that `13:30` express  time, they are not just numbers , but  they express information about hour and minute, so in order to make difference  between `8` and `13:30`, I want to return them as they are presented  in string. For clarify problems if we just return `8`, `13`, `30` then it is not clear which one is hour, which one is minute  and  which one is just number

i have searched about regular expression  tools and  we can use  for instance following  line of codes:

```
import re
import string
text ="new notebook was sold  8 times before  13:30 in given shop"
x = re.findall("[0-5][0-9]", text)
y =re.findall("\d+",text)
print(x,y)
```

The first one returns two digit numbers (in this case `13` and `30`) and second one returns all numbers (8,13,3) but how to return as they are presented in the list? so answer should be [8,13:30]?

here is one link which contains  information about all  regular expression  options :[regular expression](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp)

let us take one of the answer :

```
x = re.findall(r'\d+(?::\d+)?', text)
```

here d+ means match one or more digits., then comes

```
(?::\d+)?
```

? -means Zero or one occurrences,() is group option, for instance following syntax means

```
x = re.findall("falls|stays", txt)
#Check if the string contains either "falls" or "stays":
```

so this statement

```
 x = re.findall(r'\d+(?::\d+)?', text)
```

does it mean  , that any digit following by one or : symbol and then following by  digit again? what about 8?

Comment: no idea... I just fixed some minor stuffs to (hope so) improve readability. By the way SO is not a _forum_... and your question *could* be even on the boundary to be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = re.findall(r'\d+(?::\d+)?', text)
```

- `\d+` one or more digits
- `(?:` non-capturing group
- `?` optional

Meaning digits optionally followed by a colon and digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

text = "new notebook was sold 8 times before 13:30 in given shop"

pattern = re.compile(r'\b(?:\d{1,2}:\d{2}|\d+)\b')
matches = pattern.findall(text)

print(matches)
# ['8', '13:30']
```

What you need are capturing groups `()` and OR `|`.
All capturing groups are returned if either a number `\d+` or a time is matched.

For example, if you also want dates as well, just add it between the OR's:

```
text = "new notebook was sold 8 times before 13:30 on 2023-03-04 in given shop"
pattern = re.compile(r'\b(?:\d{1,2}:\d{2}|20\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}|\d+)\b')
```

Comment: thank you for answer, from one  point it seems  very difficult to  understand or  explain someone,it is possible to  make  it  a bit more simple way

Comment: @neuralscience how would you make it simpler? As regexes go, this one isn't complicated at all, it's just a bunch of options strung together, and each option is rather straightforward as to what it's matching.

Comment: I mean theoretically you could split by whitespace and a try/except block with a typcast e.g. datetime. strptime, for each type you are expecting, but I would second @MattDMo comment that regex is the way to go. You can try regex101.com in insert the regex, there you get an explainaiton for each character used.

Comment: thank you sir for your comments i will remember about it

Answer (score 0):

```
r='([\d]+)[\D]+([\d:{1}]+)'
y=re.search(r,text)
y.groups(1)
```

This will find >=1 number and save as a group, then >=1 non number, then >1 number plus a ':' within, and save as another group.